# Virtual Environment not being recognized in python interpreter

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

I have created a virtual environment in vscode and also activated it, however, the virtual environment is not being shown in python interpreter path. only the default python path is being shown. Also when I am trying to install any module in terminal while the venv active, it just shows that Unable to create process using "" install module. Please help me with this problem.

Here are the steps which I used to create the virtual environment:

1. I installed the virtualenv module by using the command 'pip install virtualenv'
2. I created the virtual environment in a folder by using the command 'virtualenv myprojectenv'
3. Then I activated the virtual env by using the command '.\myprojectenv\Scripts\activate.ps1'
4. It took me inside the virtual environment. Then I tried to install the module 'flask' by using the command 'pip install flask', but then it showed the error - 'Unable to create process using "" '
   [image]

Also please provide me a solution in layman's language as I am a beginner in the coding field

Comment: could you pls post the steps you used to create the Virtual Environment, also could you please post a screenshot of the error you get in the terminal.

Comment: I have added the steps in the question.

Comment: Instead of screenshots, it is recommended to use copy-paste (of relevant parts) from the terminal (formatted as code) in the question. This makes the question more easy to be searched for.

Comment: It seems that you've done everything correctly. Running `activate.ps1` should inject the `Scripts` folder (with pip.exe and python.exe) to the `PATH` of the process. Did you resolve this already?  One option would be to use plain `venv` instead of `virtualenv`. Also, as a workaround you can use `myprojectenv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install flask` to force the usage of the pip of your virtual environment.

Comment: Python3 comes with venv module, you don't need to install virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

to install flask write the code in the terminal:-
py -m pip install flask

On running this code in Virtual Studio Code, these 5 packages  will be installed automatically along with flask.

1. Werkzeug
2. itsdangerous
3. click
4. Jinja
5. MarkupSafe