# Created a virtual environment using 'virtualenv' but unable to use the python interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, virtualenv

I installed `virtualenv` using `pip install vitualenv` in my Windows 10. Then, I created a folder named `venv_test` (path= `C:\Users\JATIN SAINI\Desktop\venv_test`) to test creating a virtual environment in it. 
 I have my `Python 3.9.6` globally installed at path `C:\Users\JATIN SAINI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\` and it is also added to the Environment Variables in my Windows. 
 
I typed the following commands after changing directory to `venv_test`:

```
C:\Users\JATIN SAINI\Desktop\venv_test>virtualenv env
created virtual environment CPython3.9.6.final.0-64 in 758ms
  creator CPython3Windows(dest=C:\Users\JATIN SAINI\Desktop\venv_test\env, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=C:\Users\JATIN SAINI\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==21.1.2, setuptools==57.0.0, wheel==0.36.2
  activators BashActivator,BatchActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator

C:\Users\JATIN SAINI\Desktop\venv_test>cd env\Scripts\

C:\Users\JATIN SAINI\Desktop\venv_test\env\Scripts>activate

(env) C:\Users\JATIN SAINI\Desktop\venv_test\env\Scripts>python
Unable to create process using 'c:\users\jatin saini\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe'

(env) C:\Users\JATIN SAINI\Desktop\venv_test\env\Scripts>pip list
Unable to create process using 'c:\users\jatin saini\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe "C:\Users\JATIN SAINI\Desktop\venv_test\env\Scripts\pip.exe" list'
```

The error is `Unable to create process`.

- I have tried completely uninstalling python from my system and reinstalling but same error comes!

I read in the documentation of `virtualenv` that :

> Created python virtual environments are usually not self-contained. A complete python packaging is usually made up of thousands of files, so it’s not efficient to install the entire python again into a new folder. Instead virtual environments are mere shells, that contain little within themselves, and **borrow most from the system python** (this is what you installed, when you installed python itself). This does mean that if you upgrade your system python your virtual environments might break, so watch out. The upside of this, referring to the system python, is that creating virtual environments can be fast.

Now, according to this as my system python is working fine, it should also work fine in the virtual environment but I really can't figure out why!!!

> Similar question [Virtual Environment not being recognized in python interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65551371/virtual-environment-not-being-recognized-in-python-interpreter?newreg=b18d60ae16a44965bf95ccc0fc02ea55)

Comment: Try running python using its full path... like <virtual-env>/bin/python -v

Comment: @sureshvv 
(env) C:\Users\JATIN SAINI\Desktop\venv_test\env\Scripts>"C:\Users\JATIN SAINI\Desktop\venv_test\env\Scripts\python" -v  
Unable to create process using 'c:\users\jatin saini\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -v   
Same error.

Comment: Don't use virtualenv. Use module venv. python3 -m venv. Remove virtualenv and start over.

Comment: okay, I will. But I read that "virtualenv" is the one stop solution for all things virtual env. in python and "venv" which comes pre-installed with python has less features. So, it would be great if this worked! btw thanks.

Comment: virtualenv was a python2 solution that doesn't want to die :)